# Why does IntelliJ IDEA compile Scala so slowly?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using idea 9.0.3 which is the latest release. When I write some scala source code in Idea, it takes several seconds to compile and run. This shouldn't be that slow, Is this normal?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490383/java-compile-speed-vs-scala-compile-speed

Comment: The top answers to this question provide useful explanations of how compiling Scala is different from compiling Java. I'm going to merge them into [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490383/java-compile-speed-vs-scala-compile-speed) that @AaronNovstrup suggested. (If this question isn't meant as a duplicate of that, then it's too broad.)