# Complete code base is recompiled on every change in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I use standard plugin for Scala in IntelliJ idea.

My workflow is the following:

1. Write some simple program (10 lines of code)
2. Compile it (wait for awhile), then make some changes again and wait the same about of time while it compiles everything.

And it seems it compiles not only pieces I've changed, but all code.

Comparing to Scala IDE for Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA compiles in 20 times slower.

So, why? Maybe there is some special way to configure Scala plugin (I use default setting - just put JAVA_HOME and Scala location there)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does IntelliJ IDEA compile Scala so slowly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606591/why-does-intellij-idea-compile-scala-so-slowly). See also: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2011/10/05/real-fsc-support/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning on fsc might help (it sets the Scala compiler up as a daemon / service rather than starting it from scratch every time). In Scala facet of your project:

[image]

click "Use project FSC", then click Settings and select a compiler library for fsc.

If you're doing a larger project you probably want to use sbt to manage your build, as it does incremental compilation. IDEA has a good sbt plugin you can try.

Comment: yes, it helped. thx. Oki.. will see to sbt plugin as well.. how to use it