# intellij idea 11, scala slow execution

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does IntelliJ IDEA compile Scala so slowly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606591/why-does-intellij-idea-compile-scala-so-slowly)

I've just setup a scala plugin and created a new scala project.
The problem is that when I run the scala script the execution is VERY slow - it takes 4 sec to just `println("hello")`
It has nothing to do with compiling, since I disabled the make on run and the execution time is constant every time I run.
Just to compare: in eclipse with scala plugin this is half a sec.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606591/why-does-intellij-idea-compile-scala-so-slowly

Comment: Would you care to explain how the question about execution is a duplicate of a question about compiling. Like I said, this is NOT related to compilation, since the compilation is not invoked and the output class file is not changed.

Comment: If you're talking about scripts, then yes, they are re-compiled every time. That's why they're scripts, not compiled classes. If you put it inside an object that extends `App`, you'll find it runs much more quickly (and compiles more quickly, with fsc turned on). I don't know why scripts don't use fsc; maybe because not many people use them. Try asking on the JetBrains forums.