# What is the 8-bit simulator in scala compiler and how to launch it?

Tags: scala, scalac

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490383/java-compile-speed-vs-scala-compile-speed) and saw:

> scalac includes an 8-bit simulator of a fully armed and operational battle station, viewable using the magic key combination CTRL-ALT-F12 during the GenICode compilation phase.

To show what compilation phases `scalac` has, I used `scalac -Xshow-phases`.

```
phase name  id  description
----------  --  -----------
<  ...  >
     icode  23  generate portable intermediate code
```

Seems to be the relevant phase.

I compile a Hello-world program

```
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

by `scalac Hello.scala` and pressed CTRL-ALT-F12 all the way. Nothing happened. And tried `scalac -Xprint:icode Hello.scala` with CTRL-ALT-F12, nothing special as well.

How can I trigger the simulator? And what does that do?

On scala 2.11.8 and OS X 10.11.5

Comment: It is a joke! It doesn't exist

Comment: Wtf? I feel so stupid now lol.....